# Mysql Workbench composite key in diagram

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a model i'm building in workbench, and one of the tables is a many-many relationship table with a composite key made up of 3 integer values: the two foreign keys that make up the many-many relationship, and an additional identifier whose details are not relevant to my question.

I can see how in the model tab of the workbench I can tick off the checkbox to make all 3 values a component of the primary key (and it's index) and that seems to be working just fine, but when I go to the EER Diagram tab - I only see one of the columns with a key icon next to it.

Is there an additional step here, or is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT**: see attached screenshot - sorry about the yellow obscuring boxes - my company would not be pleased if I posted details, even on something so simple.

[image: Screenshot of Diagram]

Comment: I just tried in on my eer diagram and it worked fine. Are you sure it accepted your selection you made in the model tab? When you click the table and examine the breakdown, are there three checks in the respective fields under the `PK` column?

Comment: Yes - I see three ticked checkboxes - the file is saved and I've even tried closing the .mwb file and reopening.  This is on Mac OS 10.10.5 with workbench 6.3.

Comment: screenshot attached for clarification

Comment: I think this is a bug - I am getting the same problem when I use the OS X version.  The windows version shows a red key icon next to a foreign key that is part of a primary key.  This feature was added in this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54172 (maybe it never made it into the OS X version)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that has been reported. See here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92141